# How to convert string but not alphabets which is in number using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert `dynamic string` which value could be `abcd-efgh-ijkl` or `10.20.AB.20.CD`

Using below function :

```
                    function toTitleCase(str) {
                        return str.replace(/\w+/g, function (txt) {
                            return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                        });
                    }
```

Above function is working fine and giving output (which I want for string ): `Abcd-Efgh-Ijkl` but `10.20.AB.20.CD` is converting in `10.20.Ab.20.Cd` (which I don't want).

**Before** : `abcd-efgh-ijkl` and `10.20.AB.20.CD`

**After (using regex)** : `Abcd-Efgh-Ijkl` and  `10.20.Ab.20.Cd`

**Expected Solution** : `Abcd-Efgh-Ijkl` and  `10.20.AB.20.CD`

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the pattern specifications? Do you just want to skip chunks of dot-separated double alphanumeric chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can do a check to confirm that the `str` doesn't has any numbers and then process the `str` accordingly.

**Details**:

`!(/\d+/g).test(str)` - confirms the presence of **no digits**

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
  return !(/\d+/.test(str)) ? str.replace(/\w+/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }) : str;
}

console.log(toTitleCase("abcd-efgh-ijkl"))
console.log(toTitleCase("10.20.AB.20.CD"))
```

Comment: The `g` in `!(/\d+/g).test(str)` makes no sense - looking for a single match is enough here.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\b[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:\.[A-Z0-9]{2})*\b|\b([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)\b/g, function (txt, $1, $2) {
        return $1 ? $1.toUpperCase() + $2.toLowerCase() : txt;
    });
}
console.log(toTitleCase("abcd-efgh-ijkl"))
console.log(toTitleCase("10.20.AB.20.CD"))
console.log(toTitleCase("ACdf"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l0z5ZF/4)

**Details**

- `\b[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:\.[A-Z0-9]{2})*\b` - a chunk of dot-separated double alphanumeric chars that will be matched and inserted into the result as is:

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `[A-Z0-9]{2}` - 2 letters or digits
  - `(?:\.[A-Z0-9]{2})*` - 0+ sequences of a `.` and then 2 digits or letters
  - `\b` - a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([a-z][A-Z])` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1`): a letter
- `([a-zA-Z]*)` - Group 2 (referred to with `$2`): 0+ ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: I am getting  
1)10.20.30.AB.CD
2)ABCD EFGH 
3)ABCD-EFGH

Comment: @jsBee Share your code. Do you see `function (txt, $1, $2) {
        return $1.toUpperCase() + $2.toLowerCase();
    }` in my answer? I am sure you did not use my code.

Comment: This is what I have :
`function toTitleCase(str) {
                        return str.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-zA-Z]*)\b/g, function (txt, $1, $2) {
                            return $1.toUpperCase() + $2.toLowerCase();
                        });
                    }
                    occupancylist += '<a href="#" class="elementLink"><li style="list-style: none" data-elementid="' + sortedElements[ele].options.elementId + '">' + sortedElements[ele].options.icon.options.html + ' ' + toTitleCase(sortedElements[ele].options.name) + '</li></a>';`

Comment: @jsBee No idea. Note that `txt` is the whole match, `$1` is what Group 1 captures and `$2` is what Group 2 captures. You may rename those variables as you like. There is probably something else going on after that code or there is a problem with the debugging display.

Comment: : 'dynamic string ' could be in 'lower case' or all letters are in 'upper case '  or string which including - ex 'Abcd-efgh'

Comment: @jsBee `console.log(toTitleCase("Abcd-efgh"))` -> `Abcd-Efgh`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew : this code is working absolutely fine in JSBin ,but not in my code , But I am happy to get solution, trying to get in my code, Thank you . You almost save my day

Comment: @jsBee See a modified solution.